# How to pprint a tree data structure that is implemented using classes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tree, pretty-print, pprint

I know that `pprint` can pretty-print a nested list or dictionary, which are both types of tree structures, but I want to `pprint` a class-based tree with an arbitrary number of children, such that nodes are indented to the right depending on their level in the tree.

Can `pprint` be used to do what I want, and if so, how? I can write my own function that pretty-prints a tree, but I wanted to check if I even need to do that.

Consider the following example:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, value, *args):
        self.value = value
        self.children = args

tree = Tree("+", Tree(1), Tree("*", Tree(2), Tree(3)))
```

Here is my expected output, if we were to pretty-print the tree:

```
+
    1
    *
        2
        3
```

Again, I can certainly roll my own function, but I want to see if I can use `pprint` instead if that would be easier and I'm just overlooking something.

The [pprint documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) doesn't provide an example for my use case.

If it makes a difference, I'm using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[pprint](https://pymotw.com/2/pprint/#arbitrary-classes) works with arbitrary classes that have defined their `__repr__` method.

To get what you want here, I think you would have to manage your own nesting, at which point you could just use `print`.

```
def __repr__(self, depth=1):
    return_string = [str(self.value)]
    for child in self.children:
        return_string.extend(["\n", " " * (depth+1), child.__repr__(depth+1)])
    return "".join(return_string)
```

and then `pprint(tree)` and `print tree` both give you

```
+
  1
  *
   2
   3
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems like a doc bug that the [pprint documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) doesn't mention `__repr__`.